# show hide div radiobuttonlist using jquery

Tags: jquery, yii, radiobuttonlist

```
<td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Is Scholarship?');?></td>
<td><?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'is_scholar',array(
                    'Yes'=>'Yes',
                    'No'=>'No',),
                     array('size'=>100,'class'=>'e'.$arrMF[8],'disabled'=>$isVerify,'uncheckValue'=>null)
    );?>
<td><?php echo $form->error($model,'is_scholar');?></td>
```

I don't know how to do is.I need to use jQuery.I will select between yes or no.
if I select yes a div will be `display:block`
if I select no a div will be `display:none` and i will execute a query coming from my controller

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
$('input[id="yes"]').change(function(){
    $('div').show();
});

$('input[id="no"]').change(function(){
    $('div').hide();
});
```

checkout the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/5cRdU/**

Comment: see this if helps: http://usingjquery.com/2010/10/using-jquery-with-the-yii-framework/